# Creating ansible inventory for multiple target hosts

Tags: json, ansible, yaml, terraform

I am using terraform to create resources then using **templatefile** approach to create ansible inventory in yaml language. I am creating multiple Virtual Machines in terraform and configure them using ansible in single pipeline.

Issue I am having is yaml file uses - for lists which is giving error in ansible playbook

Outputs.tf

```
resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory" {
content = templatefile("inventory.tmpl",
{
ansible_port = "5986"
ansible_connection = "winrm"
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation = "ignore"
ansible_winrm_transport = "ntlm"
vm-ip = data.azurerm_public_ip.main.*.ip_address,
username = "testadmin",
ansible_password = "abc"
}
)
filename = "inventory.json"
}
```

inventory.tmpl

```
${jsonencode({
  "all": {
    "hosts": {
      "server": [
        for ip in vm-ip : { 
        "ansible_host": "${ip}",
        "ansible_port": 5986,
        "ansible_user": "testadmin",
        "ansible_winrm_transport": "ntlm",
        "ansible_connection": "winrm",
        "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation": "ignore",
        "ansible_password": "abc"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})}
```

inventory.json

```
{"all":{"hosts":{"server":{"ansible_connection":"winrm","ansible_host":"343434","ansible_password":"abc","ansible_port":5986,"ansible_user":"testadmin","ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation":"ignore","ansible_winrm_transport":"ntlm"}}}}
```

inventory.yaml

```
all:
  hosts:
    server:
    - ansible_connection: winrm
      ansible_host: 40.88.14.205
      ansible_password: abc
      ansible_port: 5986
      ansible_user: testadmin
      ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
      ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
```

Is my approach right then how to remove "-" from code or am I doing something wrong.

Edited:

I am converting json file to yaml file using bash in pipeline.

```
python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; yaml.safe_dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)' < inventory.json > inventory.yaml
```

Comment: Could you please share where you are getting the `- in the YAML`. as the current YAML looks fine to me

Comment: Edited Question. @ShubhamVaishnav

Comment: Where is the YAML coming from? Your code shows how you get the JSON but not the YAML.

Comment: Why not just yamlencode the output instead of jsonencode it and then run it through that Python script?

Comment: Anyway your issue is that you are incorrectly using a list for the variables at the host level. Either you want multiple hosts and the list should be one level up (child of `hosts`) or you want a single host and you should remove the list altogether.

Comment: I want to have multiple hosts.

Comment: YamlEncode is not working for me and child of list also not working. could you show me how you will create list with "child of hosts" may be I am creating it wrong @ydaetskcoR

Comment: ${jsonencode({
  "all": {
      "hosts": [
        for ip in vm-ip : { 
        "ansible_host": "${ip}",
        }
      ]
      vars:{
        "ansible_port": 5986,
        "ansible_user": "testadmin",
        "ansible_winrm_transport": "ntlm",
        "ansible_connection": "winrm",
        "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation": "ignore",
        "ansible_password": "abc"
      }
  }
})}

Comment: I am a bit lost in your question. Your _inventory.json_ is correct. And running that JSON into the Python script you are providing does give the right YAML.

Comment: I need to control multiple IPs using ansible in YAML inventory.I will check check with your answer, will update on this.

Comment: I am not able to get list of IPs in Json to Yaml correctly. Any ways its fine with Yaml encode as well.

Comment: @bhupinder you shouldn’t change anything in your `tf`, I made a list because I don’t have an Azure server farm to test it on, but in your case it should go fine.

Comment: Still I need to change json to yaml in file extension.

Comment: Right, indeed :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out by [@ydaetskcoR's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429760/creating-ansible-inventory-for-multiple-target-hosts#comment110442373_62429760), your inventory is wrong because you need the list of hosts to be an immediate child of the `hosts` attribute.

---

Note that the list you end up with is produced by the use of the brackets `[]`, producing tuples, around `for` in your Terraform template as opposed to the use of the bracket `{}`, producing objects.

> The type of brackets around the `for` expression decide what type of result it produces. The above example uses `[` and `]`, which produces a tuple. If `{` and `}` are used instead, the result is an object, and two result expressions must be provided separated by the `=>` symbol.

<sup>*https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions*</sup>

---

If your structure, should look like `all > server1, server2, server3`

Then your inventory should be

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
      ansible_host: 10.0.0.2
      ansible_port: 5986
    server2:
      ansible_host: 10.0.0.3
      ansible_port: 5986
    server3:
      ansible_host: 10.0.0.4
      ansible_port: 5986
```

This is an approach for a Terraform template producing this:

```hcl
${yamlencode({
  "all": {
    "hosts": {
      for i, ip in vm-ip:
        "server${i+1}" => {
          "ansible_host": "${ip}",
          "ansible_port": 5986
        }
    }
  }
})}
```

Which gives this valid *inventory.yaml*:

```yaml
"all":
  "hosts":
    "server1":
      "ansible_host": "10.0.0.2"
      "ansible_port": 5986
    "server2":
      "ansible_host": "10.0.0.3"
      "ansible_port": 5986
    "server3":
      "ansible_host": "10.0.0.4"
      "ansible_port": 5986
```

---

On the other hand, if you want a structure like `all > server > server1, server2, server3`

Then you should make `server` a child of `all` and use the [`children` entry](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups) in your inventory:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    server:
      hosts:
        server1:
          ansible_host: 10.0.0.2
          ansible_port: 5986
        server2:
          ansible_host: 10.0.0.3
          ansible_port: 5986
        server3:
          ansible_host: 10.0.0.4
          ansible_port: 5986
```

For this one, the corresponding Terraform template would be

```hcl
${yamlencode({
  "all": {
    "children": {
      "server": {
        "hosts": {
          for i, ip in vm-ip:
            "server${i+1}" => {
              "ansible_host": "${ip}",
              "ansible_port": 5986
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})}
```

Which produce this *inventory.yaml*:

```yaml
"all":
  "children":
    "server":
      "hosts":
        "server1":
          "ansible_host": "10.0.0.2"
          "ansible_port": 5986
        "server2":
          "ansible_host": "10.0.0.3"
          "ansible_port": 5986
        "server3":
          "ansible_host": "10.0.0.4"
          "ansible_port": 5986
```

---

**Note:** for all the examples above, I am using the terraform file *test.tf* below:

```hcl
resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventory" {
  content = templatefile("inventory.tpl", {
    vm-ip = ["10.0.0.2","10.0.0.3","10.0.0.4"],
  })
  filename = "inventory.yaml"
}
```